# Getting an Uncaught reference error - require not defined when I try to import a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jestjs, importerror

This is my first time actually posting a question here, so please go easy on me. I have been trying to create a really simple app in javascript/html and I have been writing javascript code and testing in jest up until now.  Jest has been insisting that I export/import my javascript files with `module.exports = {functionName}` and `const functionName = require('./someAddressHere');`.

This has been working great so far for testing but now I want to hook up my javascript files in an index.js and start configuring my event listeners to the html. When I try the same import method I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I'm pretty new to web development so is there something I'm missing here or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: require is not part of the standard ECMAscript, and is actually part of node.js, though there do exist stuff like [ReqireJS](https://requirejs.org/)

Comment: I will look into this - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using webpack to package all my node modules and distribute to the front.

Answer (score 1):

Use [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and add `type="module"` in the script tag
Ex:

//./data.js

```js
export const data = {
    name: 'mydata'
};
```

//./main.js

```js
import * as data from './data.js';

alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

// html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Import</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  So my issue is that I'm trying to pass classes and functions into the front end js not really data.

Comment: it just an example is not mean you can’t use it with class and function. Can you try?